# toggle function with ! in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm reading someone's source code for their backbone app and trying to figure out this toggle function. I understand the basic of toggle is that it just switches back and forth between a setting. In the example below, it sets the favorite on a model (indicating if it's a favorite or not, I assume).  I also understand the use of `!` (meaning not). However, I don't get the logic of how this function works.

```
 toggle: function() {
      this.save({favorite: !this.get("favorite")});
    },
```

In particular, I don't get the

```
!this.get("favorite")
```

Isn't `this.get("favorite")` returning a string, namely "favorite"? or is this.get("favorite") returning the attribute which is a boolean?

Can someone kindly explain in plain english how the logic of this function works each time it would be called, toggling between the two states.

Comment: I think it also casts the argument to boolean.

Comment: not particulary !! does cast it to a boolean

Comment: Well it would return a boolean value, though opposite of the argument, so `!1` would return `false` while `!0` would return `true`. So yes, it's not technically a `cast` but return values shall be boolean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

! is a negation.

The function probably returns a boolean, which result then is inverted.

So in this case it would toggle `favorite` between true and false

Comment: I thought this.get("favorite") returned a string, namely "favorite." or is this.get("favorite") return whatever the attribute favorite was set to, namely a boolean?

Comment: you should give us your get() method to clarify this

Comment: it's a backbone.js app, get is from backbone

Comment: so its probably aquivalent to 
 this.save({favorite: !this.favorite}); 
hth

Answer (score 4):

The JavaScript `!` operator negates a boolean result:

```
!true == false
!false == true
```

Read ! as "not".

Therefore the posted code snippet sets `favorite` to the opposite of what it's currently set to.

Comment: I understand that ! negates a boolean but I thought this.get("favorite") returned a string, namely "favorite." Or is "favorite" the attribute and does this.get("favorite") return whatever the boolean attribute "favorite" is set to?

Comment: Without seeing the backend code that saves the setting, it is safe to assume that this save function snippet sets the favorite to the opposite of what it currently is based on backend values pre-defined, whether true / false, 0 / 1, 'on' / 'off', etc...

Comment: this.get in this case returns the current value of favorite. This is probably defined to false by default, and thus should always remain a boolean.

Comment: it does not have to be defined i guess, !undefined is false

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript code to illustrate casting from string to boolean with '!' and '!!'**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var myobject = {
    getmystring : function(){
      return "enceladus";
    },
    getmyboolean : function(key){
      return true;
    },
    toggle: function() {
          document.write(this.getmystring());  //enceladus
          document.write(!this.getmystring()); //false
          document.write(!!this.getmystring()); //true
          document.write(this.getmyboolean()); //true
          document.write(!this.getmyboolean()); //false
          document.write(!!this.getmyboolean()); //true
    }
}
myobject.toggle();
</script>
```

The concept responsible for your confusion is "javascript coercion".  The ! is coercing the string into a boolean.  The keyword 'this' refers to the object myobject.  this.getmystring("favorite") returns a string.  The !this.getmystring("favorite") coerces the string 'enceladus' to a boolean.  A populated string becomes true, so opposite of that is false.  double bang inverts it twice, back to the original which is true.

Javascript gives you plenty of rope to hang yourself with because of "type coercion", bugs crop up all the time due to an overzealous javascript interpreter converting things like 1.4E10 to the decimal 1.4.  Anything can be converted to anything, and javascript has been criticized for this counter intuitive type coercion.  Watch this short video, 1/3 the way in he goes over all the insanities of javascript type coercion: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: As @mightyuhu points out, i  don't think this.get("favorite") returns a string in the backbone code in the OP. I think it's basically the same as this.favorite, which returns a boolean. I'm not saying this type coercion doesn't exist but is it really happening in this code?

Comment: but what is the point of passing "favorite" in your example as the key param? is it necessary?